# Flutter passing image string

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to send an image on instagram using flutter with the social_share package.

My issue is that i'm new with flutter and i don't find a proper way to send a path to the function `SocialShare.shareInstagramStory(imageFile.path, "#ffffff", "#000000", "https://deep-link-url");`

My images are located in the root of the flutter project in assets/images/my_images.
When i try to put the path `SocialShare.shareInstagramStory("assets/images/my_image.jpeg");`

i guess the phone doesn't know this path since it's looking on his own directory

hope i'm clear enough and thanks for your time!

Edit : here's my code:

```
onPressed: () async {
       Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
       String tempPath = tempDir.path;
       File file = File(tempDir.path);
       final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/img_1.jpeg');
       await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
       await SocialShare.shareInstagramStory(file.path);
       Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
```

i got this error :
`E/flutter (12761): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.app/cache' (OS Error: Is a directory, errno = 21)`

Comment: 2 things.1> Have you declared this image file in pubspec. yaml. 2> Did u stop and then restart the app? Hot restart wont do it. If you do not know about the first one, let me know. I will elaborate it in my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes i did both !

Answer (score 0):

So basically, what you need to do is convert your asset image into a file, then create a temporary path and store this file there. Then you can reference that path
We need to create a temporary path with this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;
```

Then create a file

```
File file = File(tempDir.path+'/img_1.jpeg');//You might have to play arounf with the /. Remove it or put it in the end to see what works
```

Now we need to write the image to this

```
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/img_1.jpeg');
  await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
```

Now you can use this temporary path to do what you want

Comment: i got an error, guess i'm doing something wrong, i have edited my post with the code

Comment: I have edited my answer with something new. Change the way how you create file

Comment: You're the moon of my days and the sun of my nights, thank you so much for your help and your time